# E-mail validation compare form does not return error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, email, asp.net-mvc-5

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}")]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Compare ("Email", ErrorMessage = "The Email and Confirm Email fields do not match.")]    
public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please advise how to reproduce. Also, did you intend to match _any character_ before `[A-Za-z]{2,4}`?

Answer (score 0):

use **nameof**

```
[RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}")]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Compare (nameof(Email), ErrorMessage = "The Email and Confirm Email fields do not match.")]    
public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it did not solve the issue.

Comment: If you are using ```ASP.Net MVC 3``` , you can use ```System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute.```


If you are using ```ASP.Net 4.5```, it's in the ```System.Component.DataAnnotations```